# How to set default currency for different stores?

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, switcher

we have created different stores with one base currency, But i need to show each store in different currency automatically, i had already changed

> Catalog Price Scope to : website

Now i had set Default Display Currency to preferred one for each websites by changing 'Current Configuration Scope'. But even after switching to different store the default currency defined is showing always.

Comment: You're changing store or website? Are you sure the website that's supposed to be run is indeed run in the URL you're accessing?

Comment: Yes everything is checked & is prefect..

Answer (score 2):

Go to *System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup*

[image: preview]

**Note** : Don't forget setup currency rate between base currency and display currency

Comment: I tried this, But have no effect at all !

Comment: You can try thiss: https://bsscommerce.com/simple-details-on-configurable-product-for-magento-2.html